# Some string values ("0", "", and " ") are defined, but (==undef)

Tags: perl, undef

In my perl script, I used `if ($a == undef)` condition, I thought it is the same as `if (not defined $a)`, where `$a` is a string as read from a csv file. However, I noticed that several string values (`"", " ", "0", "-0", "+0", "@", "a"`, and many other spaces and special characters) are defined but also `undef`.  If `undef` is only for numeric values,  it should pass `"0"`, `"+0"`, and `"-0"`.  Can anyone explain?  I understand now that I should not use `if ($a == undef)` to replace `if (not defined $a)`.

My testing code is:

```
@a_array = ("-1", "-0", "0", "+0", "1", "", " ", "@", "a", "\$", "-");
undef $a;
test_a();

foreach $a (@a_array) {
    $len_a = length($a);
    test_a();
}

sub test_a {
    if (defined $a) { print "a = $a is defined;  "} else {print "a = $a not defined; "}; 
    if ($a == undef) { print "a = $a (== undef);  "} else {print "a = $a (!= undef); "}; 
    if (length($a) > 0){ print "length of a is $len_a > 0 \n"} else {print "length of a is $len_a !> 0 \n"};
}
```

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`. Don't use [$a](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$a) as an example, consider `$x` and `$y`.

Comment: Always pass to subs _everything_ that they need, never rely on a sub "seeing" values from outside scope.  So that `test_a` sub should take `$a` as an argument (just named better).

Comment: Documentation for [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) gives good explanation of it's purpose. **undef** is separate entity and different from 0, '' or anything else.

Answer (score 7):

Perl has two equality operators: `==` and `eq`. `==` tests if the numeric form of each value is numerically equal. `eq` tests if the string form of each value is lexicographically equal. `undef` is not a string or a number, and if used as a string it is equivalent to the empty string, if used as a number it is equivalent to 0 (as is the empty string, and any string that doesn't start with something that looks like a number). You usually get warnings when this happens.

To test for `undef`, no equivalence test should be involved: use the [defined](https://perldoc.pl/functions/defined) function. Only if it is defined can it have a meaningful string or number value, and you can do subsequent tests.

The [length](https://perldoc.pl/functions/length) function returns `undef` when passed `undef`, so if you want to know if a scalar is both defined and not length 0, you only need one boolean check: `if (length $x)`. 0 and `undef` are both false results. Note that before Perl 5.12 this would cause a warning, as `length undef` attempted to use `undef` as a string, like `eq` does.

Comment: Grinnz, thank you for the clarifications. Now I understand my main confusions: 1) between eq and ==; 2) between defined and undef. I also noticed that eq and == are exchangeable between string and numeric, except for undef.  Another point is undef $x or $x = undef work for both string and numeric when assigning (clearing) values, but only works for numeric comparison.  Any corrections/comments on my observations?

Comment: @Douglas Sorry I don't really follow what you are trying to say. `eq` is always a string comparison, `==` is always a numeric comparison, there are values which are different strings but the same number, and vice versa. `undef` has nothing to do with comparisons of either kind, and is string-equal to the empty string and numeric-equal to 0.

Comment: Thank you again.  I understand the problem now.  My last comment do not make much sense since I used == and undef incorrectly (though it worked partially).